# Implementing the All functionality in SQL

Tags: c#, sql, linq, aggregate

I'm trying to write an SQL query where all of a certain group meets a condition.

**Update**
The Simplifed Table Structure would look like this

```
ID, TitleID,  BlockFromSale
---------------------------
1 | 1  | true
2 | 1  | true
3 | 1  | true
4 | 2  | false
5 | 2  | true
```

this table would only return the the items TitleID 1.

In actuality I only need the title ID and not the whole item but either will satisfy the conditions.

How Could I write This Linq Query in SQL?

```
var Query = Data.Items.GroupBy(t => t.TitleID).Where(i => i.All(b => b.BlockFromSale == true));
```

I try to look at the Sql Query but it just instantly casts it to an object.

Basically I just Need a query that Grabs out all TitleIDs who for each item BlockFromSale is set to true so for the example from the table above it would only return TitleID, 1

Comment: What's the table structure look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't an easy way to do what your asking but a simple but some what slow way would be to use a subQuery

```
SELECT DISTINCT i.TitleID 
FROM Items i 
WHERE i.TitleID not in 
(SELECT DISTINCT TitleID 
 FROM items it
 WHERE it.BlockFromSale = 0)
```

so it will remove the titleids who have a false.

Comment: This does exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to see the generated SQL of a LINQ query by using the `Log` property of the query.  [How to: Display Generated SQL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386961%28v=vs.110%29.aspx%20How%20to:%20Display%20Generated%20SQL) shows an example of this.  Basically, the web site shows this example:

```
db.Log = Console.Out;
IQueryable<Customer> custQuery =
    from cust in db.Customers
    where cust.City == "London" 
    select cust;

foreach(Customer custObj in custQuery)
{
    Console.WriteLine(custObj.CustomerID);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to check predicate `p` for all rows of a set you can write

```
NOT EXISTS (... WHERE NOT(p))
```

Because `All(p) == !Any(!p)` in pseudo-syntax.

I would guess that ORMs do it this way, too.

Comment: How would this full select be written?

Select i.TitleID from Items i
Group by i.TitleID
Having Not Exists (i.Blockfromsale = 0)?

Comment: I keep seeing that Everywhere But I still have no Idea how to implement this with a groupby

Comment: This has no relationship to group by at all. This is simply a predicate that you can put anywhere a predicate is accepted. For example in a WHERE clause.

Comment: Thanks for that Clarification.  Do you happen to know I can can get all titleids whose all of the items are set to true for block from sale